# Is it possible to make dough with no water or milk? Please see details for specific ingredients list

Tags: dough

I found this business online selling frozen yogurt toppings, and they list the ingredients used in each product. This one is for sticky rice:

Ingredients: HYDROXYPROPYL DISTARCH PHOSPHATE, GLUTINOUS RICE, MALTOSE, SUGAR, SALT.

As you can see, it contains no liquid as a binding agent. No water, milk or the commonly used coconut milk.

I am wondering if you can use viscous liquids like honey, liquid glucose or in this case, the (possibly liquid) maltose, as a binding agent.

The ingredients list is from: https://www.bossenstore.com/collections/no-cook-toppings/products/original-mini-mochi

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The ingredient list usually skips water, unless it's a liquid product (juice, drink). That doesn't mean water wasn't used, or is absent, but often the product after being dried contains very small amounts of it (and difficult to measure, and changing with air moisture and small changes to technological process, and so on). Water being mostly nutritionally neutral is not essential in ingredient lists, and the ingredient list is not a recipe. Also, sometimes the water comes from other sources - e.g. egg, or some syrup, or even butter/margarine. I believe some doughs may be based entirely on fats as liquid too (e.g. clarified butter), but a liquid in one form or another is a must.

As for 'liquid glucose', in common syrup form it's just a water solution (and of course can be used as the binder.) Liquid dehydrated glucose (or sugar) will be extremely hot - to the point of scorching other ingredients, plus it solidifies into hard glassy substance once it cools down. This process is used to make some sweet, in particular mixing with seeds, like sesame, where the heat brings out extra flavor in the seeds. But that's definitely not dough.

[image: sesame seed candies]

Comment: Oh thanks, I was thinking perhaps they just did not include water on the ingredients list, in Australia (this product is sold in America but manufactured in China), all food lists water as an ingredient if it is used, as far as I was aware. This means even things like biscuits and lollies lists water as an ingredient. I've always wondered if water can be excluded in the ingredients list for dried products, since the water evaporates during cooking anyway. Would it be possible to tell from reading an ingredients list, if water is actually not used, or if it is simply not listed?

Comment: @StephanieChen-Xu: That's dubious. Manufacturers often make the ingredient list more or less inaccurate (to the extent permitted by law) to avoid providing ready recipe for competition to use or for customers to skip the purchase and cook the thing on their own.  Your best bet is to google *"product name" recipe* and find the recipes that match the ingredient list and final look best. OTOH, unless it's freeze-dried, you can be quite sure it will contain at least some water.

Comment: @SF. : I wouldn't be surprised if the obfuscation of product lists wasn't to make something 'seem better' than it really was.  I can't remember what I was looking at, but it had some "ingredient" that was a mix (in parenthesis was a list of 3 ingredients after it), then sugar.  If the three hadn't been lumped together, I suspect 'sugar' would have been first on the list.

Comment: Unless it was puffed rice, they also would have needed water to cook the rice. Here are the US rules: "Water added in making a food is considered to be an ingredient. The added water must be identified in the list of ingredients and listed in its descending order of predominance by weight. If all water added during processing is subsequently removed by baking or some other means during processing, water need not be declared as an ingredient."

Comment: @ChefAndy: Yes, puffed rice (plain) doesn't require water. To make other ingredients "stick" though water is required - although it's then removed. And the title confused me - puffed rice is more like popcorn, it's not a dough.

Comment: @SF Well, molten sugar could certainly make the other ingredients stick.

Comment: @ChefAndy: ...or whatever charred remains of these ingredients, depending on what you try to use it with. Sugar caramelizes at 186 °C and to get it liquid enough to actually pour / mix with other ingredients you'll need to exceed that by a bit.